# How to go about implementing adaptive warmups in JMH (in Scala)

Tags: java, scala, microbenchmark, jmh, sbt-jmh

I'm currently getting started in integrating JMH into a Scala Project and would like to implement a way to do adaptive warmups. What do I mean by apative warmups? Instead of defining a fixed number of warmup iterations, I would like to automatically determine the number of warmups it takes to get a stable runtime and then start measuring.

Has anyone already implemented this feature or is there a good reason why nobody did?

My naive attempt would be running a benchmark without warmup iterations, checking  when runtimes seem to stabilize and if they don't try again with more iterations until the output seems stable. This number of iterations would then be used as the warmup iteration value when doing the actual measurements.

Comment: The problem is at "when warmup seem to stabilize" - you need a human who runs things several times to make sense of the results, because there might be a case that something seems to stabilized but a few seconds more and the numbers change again. Additionally, for reproducibility and any meaningful comparison (e.g. for regressions) you need to have reproducible environment - same hardware, no other tasks, same settings. If the number of iterations changes between runs, it's apples to oranges. If that number changes someone should take a closer look why - automating it kinda defeats the purpose